# Syntax to reverse-query a cached queryset

Tags: django

I have the following 3 models related by Foreign Key as following:

```
class Seller(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Genre(models.Model):
    seller= models.ForeignKey(Seller, related_name="genre",  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Book(models.Model):
    genre= models.ForeignKey(Genre, related_name="book",  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And I want to retrieve the whole 3 tables in one database query, by querying the Seller objects, as following:

```
sellers = Seller.objects.select_related('genre', 'book').all().values('name')
seller_df = pd.DataFrame(list(sellers))
```

What is the syntax to filter for books carried by a particular seller, without hitting the database again (by utilizing either the `Seller` queryset or the pandas `seller_df`)

```
seller1 = seller_df ['name'].iloc[0]
seller1_books = Book.objects.filter(...)

seller_last = seller_df ['name'].iloc[-1]
seller_last_books = Book.objects.filter(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know so mach about caching but I know something that you like:

We use `select_related` when the object is single like onetoone or fk.
.
for many to many or reverse fk like your example use `prefetch_related`

Comment: This is a chained Foreign Key relation. ```Seller``` is the top level. When I use ```select_related('genre', 'book')```, it retrieves all 3 level querysets. Now I am looking for how to get the ```Book``` objects from the ```Seller``` objects (either by the dataframe or by the queryset itself).

Comment: Read this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prefetch_related-and-select_related-functions-in-django/) can help you